# Access Microsoft Graph resources with an App access token (no user sign-in)

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I own an institutional e-mail account and I want to access its content (and send emails) using a PHP web application I'm writing, and I want it to access this account without sign-in from the user (they will be logged to my application, that will send predefined messages based upon user's actions).

I registered the application using Microsoft [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) using this institutional account credentials, and got my `client_id` and `client_secret` (password).

I'm using the code below to perform authentication based on [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service):

```
function preformat($string) {
    return "<pre>".htmlentities($string)."</pre>";
}

function getGraphAccessToken($domain, $client_id, $password) {
    $graph_endpoint="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    $token_endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".$domain."/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    $token_postdata = implode("&",[
        "grant_type=client_credentials",
        "client_id=".urlencode($client_id),
        "client_secret=".urlencode($password),
        "scope=".urlencode($graph_endpoint)
        ]
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_endpoint); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token_postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $token_json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $token_object = json_decode($token_json);
    return "Authorization: ".$token_object->token_type." ".$token_object->access_token;
}

function queryGraph($auth_header, $feed){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/".$feed); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth_header,"Accept:application/json;odata=minimalmetadata","Content-Type:application/json;odata=minimalmetadata","Prefer:return-content"));
    $graph_query = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $graph_query;
}

$auth_header=getGraphAccessToken($domain,$client_id,$client_secret);
echo preformat($auth_header);
$query_me=queryGraph($auth_header,"me");
echo preformat($query_me);
```

This code succeeds to grab the access token and requests from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ expecting to receive the institutional account's info (as a success test). However, I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": 
"Current authenticated context is not valid for this request.
 This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in.
 For example, /me requires a signed-in user.
 Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.
 Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps
 and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3073f561-43db-49d3-9851-7f50037abb61",
      "date": "2018-12-31T17:28:45"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think that error message could be any clearer. "For example, /me requires a signed-in user."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `/me` with app-only authentication, you need to reference the user via their `userPrincipalName` - `/users/{upn}`. After all, how would Graph know which "me" you are referring too?

Comment: Thank you! But now I have a `"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."` response.

Comment: You need to request the proper scopes for the operation you want to execute and have them consented by the tenant Admin.

Comment: Happy new year! And thank you, I'll try to discover who is admin for that in my organization. I understood I must prepare a special link for they to access and authorize, am I right? Once they do, is it permanent?

Comment: Its permanent for the scopes they consent to. If you add a scope later, you'll need to reconsent.